# Using data from one table to update columns of other table using Stored Procedures in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a **Stored Procedure** with intended action as-

When a user tries to contact me using the **Contact Us** Page,the details like the name,email and message are stored in the table called **contactus (TABLE 1)** . The **Stored Procedure** will check if the email id is associated with an account (based on data of another table called **users (TABLE 2)**). If it does, then it updates the value of *account_exists* as **true** in **contactus (TABLE 1)** table. Else, it sets that value to **false**.

I have tried some code, but I am unable to execute it due to syntax error. Also, the documentation does not clearly mention the syntax of what I want to do.

**Here is what I tried**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `set_data_basedon_other_table`(IN em VARCHAR(500))
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email) AS noofaccounts FROM users WHERE email=em

       INSERT INTO contactus
        IF noofaccounts>0 THEN
       SET account_exists=true
       WHERE email=em
       ELSE
       SET account_exists=false
       WHERE email=em
 ENDIF      
END
```

Comment: (1) No statements termination, `;` must be used for each statement terminating (2) Used local variable is not defined (3) INSERT cannot update existing row - it may insert new, one more, row only (4) IF statement cannot be used in a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SP not needed, single query is enough:

```sql
UPDATE contactus
SET account_exists = EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                              FROM users 
                              WHERE email = @em )
WHERE email = @em;
```

---

In SP form it will be

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `set_data_basedon_other_table`(IN em VARCHAR(500))
BEGIN
DECLARE noofaccounts BIGINT;
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email) 
    INTO noofaccounts 
    FROM users 
    WHERE email=em;
IF noofaccounts>0 THEN
    UPDATE contactus
        SET account_exists=true
        WHERE email=em;
ELSE
    UPDATE contactus
        SET account_exists=false
        WHERE email=em;
ENDIF;
END
```

Comment: I am aware of that. Since I am learning and specifically SP, so I said why not?

Comment: @Asish Nothing prevents to move this query into SP. of course this makes no sense but is possible nevertheless.

Comment: Can you share the documentation where this syntax is used? I want to know more.

Comment: @Asish Corrected SP form of your code added. *Can you share the documentation where this syntax is used?* dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index.html